# How to increment a string having number fields in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a slot number like `slot001`. Now I have to increment it by some `user_input` value (say 5). the output should be:

```
slot001
slot002
slot003
slot004
slot005
```

I have tried writing a piece of code but it is not able to differentiate between `slot001` and `slot1`. The string length is not fixed, however it will be word-digit format.

My approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Pr_procedure_poc 
(
    slot_numin    IN VARCHAR2,
    range_countin IN NUMBER
) is
 v_slt_num     NUMBER;
 v_slot        VARCHAR2(100) := slot_numin;
 v_slt_var     VARCHAR2(100);
 v_temp        VARCHAR2(100);

begin
        SELECT Regexp_substr(slot_numin, '\d+') 
        INTO   v_slt_num
        FROM   dual;

        SELECT Regexp_substr(slot_numin, '\D+')
        INTO   v_slt_var
        FROM   dual;

FOR i IN 0 .. (range_countin -1) LOOP  --range_countin :=user input to increament the string

v_temp := v_slt_num + i;
v_slot := v_slt_var||v_temp;

end loop;

end
Pr_procedure_poc;
```

output for  slot_numin='abc001' and Range=10:

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc8
abc9
abc10
```

output for  slot_numin='abc1' and Range=10:

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc8
abc9
abc10
```

Expected Output:
output for  slot_numin='abc001' and Range=10:

abc001

```
abc002
abc003
abc004
abc005
abc006
abc007
abc008
abc009
abc010
```

output for  slot_numin='abc1' and Range=10:

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc8
abc9
abc10
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your regexp to find is there leading zeros or not and if yes then use format with leading zeros in your `to_char()` function:

```
v_temp := to_char(v_slt_num + i, 'fm09999');
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rusty's short answer:

```
declare
  slot_numin varchar2(100) := 'slot0001';
  varpart    varchar2(100) := regexp_substr(slot_numin, '\D+');
  numpart    varchar2(100) := regexp_substr(slot_numin, '\d+');
  digits     number := length(numpart);
begin
  for i in 1..9 loop
   dbms_output.put_line(
     varpart
     || to_char((to_number(numpart) + i),'fm'||rpad('0',digits,'0'))
     );
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
slot0002
slot0003
slot0004
slot0005
slot0006
slot0007
slot0008
slot0009
slot0010
```